# laravel blade don't get the uploaded file from storage using href

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-10

in previous versions of laravel framework i could simply get the uploaded post_file by using this line in my blade:
`<a href="{{ asset("/".$file->post_file)}}" target="_blank">`
or
`<a href="{{ asset("/".$file->post_file)}}" download="{{$file->post_file}}">` 
but when i started using laravel 10 i those methods dont work anymore
the url i get is incorrect
the link should be
http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/file/123456_file.pdf
but instead of this i get
http://127.0.0.1:8000/123456_file.pdf

the files are well saved in public/upload.
for info i'm on windows i have other projects with laravel 7 and the methods work fine.
Best regards

Comment: Did you run php artisan storage:link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use it like this
href="{{ asset('/storage/upload/file/'.$file->post_file.'')}}"

Comment: i appreciate your support thank you